# Time conversion in java

Tags: java

How can I convert unix time in java ?

Get this :

```
~#>date -d @1305176400
Thu May 12 00:00:00 CDT 2011
```

But in java

Comment: To what type do you want to convert? to String type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
                  .format(new java.util.Date (epoch*1000));
```

See: http://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: The default format for Date matches his requirement as far as I can see.

Comment: So it appears but I thought it'd be nice to give him an more specific example as well as a link to further learning :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
Date d = new Date(1305176400 * 1000L);
System.out.println(d);
```

prints

```
Thu May 12 06:00:00 BST 2011
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at SimpleDateFormat class. Documentation describes how to craft correct format that can be used to convert from date to String and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date date = new Date(msSinceEpoch);  //note: input is ms since epoch, not seconds
String s = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(date);
```

that will make sure the formatting is consistent for your default locale.